# Reserve space for a column in mysql for efficient UPDATEs?

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to append data to a BLOB column at a high rate. I suppose the default mysql behavior is to reposition the data on disk as the blob grows larger, so for a big number of UPDATEs the performance will suffer as opposed to having the new rows inserted instead?

How do I make mysql reserve a chunk on the disk to speed up such updates?

I'm don't have a table with a certain storage engine at the moment - I'm trying to verify if this is possible in any engine mysql supports.

Comment: @eggyal, any - as long as one of them is better for this, I'll use it.

Comment: InnoDB splits variable-length columns across 16KB pages, so concatenating extra data onto an existing column will either remain within an existing page or spill across new ones (the same as if the record were created fresh with the new length `BLOB`); there are however some pecularities--see [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-row-format-overview.html) for more info.

Comment: If your application depends on the speed, run a test how each storage engine scales over the size of your blob, ie run it and plot the time for each 1000 updates. This comes in handy if the performance degrades for some reason later on (errors, bad hardware etc) if one storage engine updates 1kB as fast as 1mB: go for it : )

Comment: Cliché: Whatever storage engine you are going to use in MySQL, the most efficient database to store big data is on the file system. Just save the file on the file system and point to it in your database. It's more work on the client side, but it pays off.